# being paid or to being paid

Tags: gerunds

Could you please tell how these constructions are called and which ones are right?

1. I admit to being paid by company.
2. I admit being paid by company.
3. I enjoyed being paid by company.
4. I enjoyed to being paid by company.

Answer (score 1):

*Admit to X* means someone was accusing you of X and you confessed.  It can also mean you performed the action of admitting toward X or in the presence of X - e.g. "I admitted to the police X" and both can be used at once: "I admitted to stealing to the police".

*Admit X* doesn't convey any of that additional information - it's simply stating you admitted X.

The correct one depends on what you want to say.

*Enjoyed to X* is invalid, *enjoy* only allows *-ing* verbals after it, not *to X*.